# How do I use one black and white image as a mask for another image in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, mask

I have an image that requires a really fancy mask, created through multiple selections and subtractions of the existing image. Here's a concrete example:

- **Layer 1**: Original image, transformed into a black and white mask (would be difficult to do this with "selection to mask".
- **Layer 2**: The original image, with an image mask that is made up of the black and white image in layer 2 (this can be a one-time copy of layer 1, and does not need to be transferrable back to Layer 1.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to *use* the mask.  Something other than what Jon-Eric proposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Add Layer Mask](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-layer-mask-add.html) option and select *Grayscale copy of layer*.